# Signing certificate lost password

Tags: android, code-signing-certificate, google-play-console

I've an apk uploaded in google console and app is published already. I've lost the password for the certificate I used before.

I did try creating a new one but google console rejected the binary and insisting to re-use the original certificate to sign the app.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Google Play requirement, it is an Android requirement. In order for an update to install, the App must be signed with the same signing key as the previous version. There is no alternative.

I strongly recommend for new versions of your App, you switch to [Google Play App signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423). With this model, Google stores the App Keys (and they are probably better at not losing the key or the password than you). You have a secure upload key, but if you lose it, Google Play support can issue you with a new one.

All you can do in this situation if you have really lost the key is publish a new version of your app with a new package name, unpublish your old version, and try to get existing users to move over using communication mechanisms like email. I recommend you use Google Play App Signing for your new version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried contacting google developers support? For example, go [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3049653#ts=3049606) and click on "No". Then continue: fill the form and submit.

Comment: I submitted a request, hopefully this will solve the problem

Comment: Please when the issue is solved. Tell us about the delay it took them to answer.

Comment: Did they ever answer to you?. If yes, what is the solution?